# Showing $64$ divides $5^n-8n^2+4n-1$ without induction

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I want to show that for all positive integer values of $n$, the number $5^n-8n^2+4n-1$ is divisible by $64$. Of course, I can easily do it by induction, but are there any number theoretic ways I can utilise to prove the divisibility?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: n=1 is a counterexample. Is that the right equation?

Comment: No. For n=1, the number is exactly equal to 0, and 0 is divisible by 64.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It seems to me that the simplest way is to use the binomial expansion
$$
\begin{aligned}
5^n&=(4+1)^n=1+\binom n 1 4+\binom n2 4^2+\text{terms divisible by $4^3$}\\
&\equiv 1+4n+8n(n-1)\pmod{64}\\
&=1-4n+8n^2.
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: Oh, that is indeed something I did not think of! It is pretty nice. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Does the above imply there is some recent change on your position about answering (dupe) FAQs?

Answer (score 3):

Write $a_n=5^n-8n^2+4n-1 = 5^n+(-8n^2+4n-1)1^n$.

Then $a_n$ satisfies a linear recurrence implied by $(x-5)(x-1)^3$:
$$
a_{n+4} = 8a_{n+3}- 18a_{n+2} + 16a_{n+1} - 5a_{n}
$$

The particular expression for the recurrence is not important, except that it has integer coefficients.

Bottom line: It suffices to prove that $64$ divides $a_n$ for $n=0,1,2,3$. This is immediate because $a_0=a_1=a_2=0$ and $a_3=64$.

Comment: Well, this is a proof by induction, but not the expected one, I guess.

Comment: A nice piece of reverse engineering :-)

Answer (score 1):

Just try them all.  We know $5^{32} \equiv 1 \pmod {64}$ so if you check $[0,63]$ you are done.

Comment: Hmm, I thought of that too, but isn't this extremely tedious?

Comment: I'm not sure what is the significance of Euler's theorem $5^{32}\equiv 1 \pmod {64}$ in this situation, but in fact $5^{16}\equiv 1 \pmod {64}$

Comment: A spreadsheet is your friend. Use the fill command to make a column with the numbers from $0$ to $63$.  Write the equation and copy down.  Less than a minute.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner:  It justifies that we only need to look at numbers in the range $[0,63]$ because the exponent divides $64$..

Comment: I get it now, @RossMillikan.  Thank you for explaining

Comment: @ONGSEEHAIHCI it's not tedious if you have a computer nearby :)